# JS Replace multiple phrases

Tags: javascript, regex, string, loops, replace

I need to replace all %25 with % in **puidInp**, but only around words that mentioned in **newPuidsValues**.
I'm trying to solve it with loop, but it changes only one word at one time:

```js
var newPuidsValues = ["banner.tracking_url", "banner.userN", "banner.alt"];
var puidInp = "tyhtyh%25banner.tracking_url%25tyhtyh%25banner.userN%25tyhtyh%25banner.userN%25tyhtyh%25banner.alt%25tyhtyh";

for (var h = 0; h < newPuidsValues.length; h++) {
    const reg = new RegExp("\\D{1}\\d{2}" + newPuidsValues[h] + "\\D{1}\\d{2}", "g");
    console.log(reg);
    var puidOut = puidInp.replace(reg, "%" + newPuidsValues[h] + "%");
    console.log(puidOut);
}
```

Comment: How did it come about that you have the need to unescape raw text in your JavaScript code?

Comment: The string will be processed by algorithm, that will replace, for example %banner.userN% with generated link. Input for algorithm have to be encoded, but this macro phrases should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these small changes to your code:

- Declare `puidOut` outside of your for-loop
- Set the initial value of `puidOut` to `puidInp`
- In the for-loop, use `%25` in the RegExp you are creating to capture only the values you need to
- In the for-loop, update `puidOut` in each iteration
- Print when done

```js
var newPuidsValues = ["banner.tracking_url", "banner.userN", "banner.alt"];

var puidInp = "tyhtyh%25banner.tracking_url%25tyhtyh%25banner.userN%25tyhtyh%25banner.userN%25tyhtyh%25banner.alt%25tyhtyh";

var puidOut = puidInp;

for (var h = 0; h < newPuidsValues.length; h++) {
    const reg = new RegExp("%25" + newPuidsValues[h] + "%25", "g");
    console.log(reg);
    puidOut = puidOut.replace(reg, "%" + newPuidsValues[h] + "%");
}

console.log(puidOut);
```